# How to use PCRE Regex in SED on Mac OSX

Tags: regex, bash, macos, sed

I have the RegEx `(\[!\[|!\[)(.*)` that works on http://regexr.com/, however when I attempt to use it with `sed` like this `-e 's/(\[!\[|!\[)\(.*\)//g'` it does not work.

I have found an answer that suggests using the `-r` command instead of `-e`, however I am using Mac OSX El Capitan, and `-r` is not a supported command.

I have also found an answer that says use `-E` instead of `-r` on Mac OSX, but this did not work, and a commenter said they are not the same thing. It was also suggested to use `grep` instead of `sed`, but I am adding this search and replace to several others that are already using `sed`.

My code block looks like this and the search and replace in question is at the end of the `sed...` line:

```
# Transform the readme
if [ -f readme.md ]; then
    mv readme.md readme.txt
    if [ -f CHANGELOG.md ]; then
        cat CHANGELOG.md >> readme.txt
        rm CHANGELOG.md
    fi
    sed -i '' -e 's/^# \(.*\)$/=== \1 ===/' -e 's/ #* ===$/ ===/' -e 's/^## \(.*\)$/== \1 ==/' -e 's/ #* ==$/ ==/' -e 's/^### \(.*\)$/= \1 =/' -e 's/ #* =$/ =/' -e 's/\*\*//g' -e 's/(\[!\[|!\[)\(.*\)//g' readme.txt
fi
```

example I want to completely remove the second line that starts with `[![`from:

```
=== CMB2 Admin Extension ===
[![Build Status](https://travis-ci.org/twoelevenjay/CMB2-Admin-Extension.svg?branch=master)](https://travis-ci.org/twoelevenjay/CMB2-Admin-Extension)  
Contributors:         twoelevenjay
```

I also want it to remove lines that start with `![` like this:
`![CMB2](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/export/HEAD/cmb2/assets/banner-1544x500.png)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to completely remove the second line that starts with `[![`:

On OSX `sed` this should work for you:

```
sed -E '/^(\[!\[|!\[)/d'
```

You don't need to use a substitution; just `/d` would suffice.

Comment: This did not work for me, it prevents the other sed commands that occur before it in `sed -i '' -e  ...`  from executing and returned this: `sed: 1: "s/^# \(.*\)$/=== \1 ===/
": \1 not defined in the RE`.

Comment: Use your `sed` like this: `sed -i '' -E '/^(\[!\[|!\[)/d; s/^# (.*)$/=== \1 ===/; s/ #* ===$/ ===/; s/^## (.*)$/== \1 ==/; s/ #* ==$/ ==/; s/^### (.*)$/= \1 =/; s/ #* =$/ =/; s/\*\*//g' readme.txt`

Comment: Perfect that worked. Thank you very much. Bonus question (lol), would this script work the same on linux?

Comment: Yes, it should work fine on Linux as well because `gnu sed` also supports `-E` flag which behaves same as `-r` on Linux (though it is undocumented feature)